# Screwy use of Labeled in BarChart -- possible bug

Tags: graphics, charts

```
SetOptions[BarChart, LabelStyle -> {}];
Options[BarChart, LabelStyle]
```

When I evaluate this code

```
BarChart[Labeled[#, Rotate["label", 90 Degree], Above, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, FontSize -> 32]] & /@ Range[8]]
```

with V11.0.1 on OS X I get

[image]

When I examine the `InputForm` the labels are coded like this:

```
Text[Style[
  Rotate["label", 
   90*Degree], {LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontSize -> 32], Directive[], 
   Directive[]}], Offset[{0, 4}, {1., 1.}], ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]]
```

So we have the `LabelStyle` for `Labeled` plus duplicates of the global `LabelStyle` for `BarChart`.

```
SetOptions[BarChart, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontSize -> 12]];
```

Now I get:

[image]

with the labels configured this way:

```
Text[Style[
  Rotate["label", 
   90*Degree], {BaseStyle -> 
    Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontSize -> 24], 
          LabelStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontSize -> 32], 
   Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontSize -> 12], 
          Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontSize -> 12]}], 
 Offset[{0, 4}, {1., 1.}], ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]]
```

which confirms the duplicate of the `BarChart` `LabelStyle` `Directive`. The configuration of the styling options for these labels looks to be a mess. I'm assuming that being unable to locally style the label use the `Labeled` `LabelStyle` option is a bug?

And when I try this:

```
SetOptions[BarChart, LabelStyle -> {}];
BarChart[Labeled[
    Style[#, Directive[FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 32]], 
    Rotate["label", 90 Degree], Above] & /@ Range[8]]
```

I get this:

[image]

```
 Text[Style[Rotate["label", 90*Degree], {Directive[], Directive[]}], Offset[{0, 4}, {5., 5.}], ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]]
```

Note also that modifying the `LabeledLabel` style in my stylesheet also had no effect.

This appears to be either a bug or a design oversight. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe `BarChart[Labeled[#, Rotate["label", 90 Degree], Above, 
    Directive[Red, FontSize -> 32]] & /@ Range[8]]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll yes that works. If you post the answer I will accept. It appears like a bug through given that the solution is undocumented and is not in the form of an option.

Comment: or `BarChart[Labeled[#, Style[Rotate["label", 90 Degree], Red, 32], 
    Above] & /@ Range[8]]`?

Comment: @kglr yes that works too. I realise I had a brain fade when using `Style` above but nonetheless the rest of the pot seems like correct usage and therefore a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug. I'll seek confirmation from WRI and post accordingly. In the meantime Carl's suggestion is a work around:

```
BarChart[Labeled[#, Rotate["label", 90 Degree], Above, Directive[Red, FontSize 
-> 32]] & /@ Range[8]]
```

or alternatively from @kglr:

```
BarChart[Labeled[#, Style[Rotate["label", 90 Degree], Red, 32], Above] & /@ Range[8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears there is a missing step in the processing of `LabelStyle` within the `Labeled` wrapper, if it is to work as desired.  I think Carl Woll's work-around does this manually but it should be done automatically.

Most of the options of [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) apply not to the labels themselves but either to be object being labeled, e.g. `Background` and `Frame`, or affect the overall layout e.g. `Spacings` and `ImageSize`.  I think it makes sense for these options to be ignored by `BarChart` as it has its own directives for these aspects.

Attempting to dig through the `` Charting` `` definitions it is hard to know where exactly handling of `LabelStyle` should have been applied.

We can get some possibly useful information by turning on Charting debug printing:

```
Charting`dbPrint = Print;
```

Now:

```
SetOptions[BarChart, LabelStyle -> {}];

BarChart[
  Labeled[#, "label", Above, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, FontSize -> 32]] & /@ Range[8]
]
```

> iBarChart via: BarChart
>
> ChartParser: hasWrappedInputQ: True
>
> ChartParser: WrapperFunctions:
>   {{1}->{{Labeled,label,Above,LabelStyle->Directive[,FontSize->32]}},{2}->{{Labeled,label,Above,LabelStyle->Directive[,FontSize->32]}},{3}->{{Labeled,label,Above,LabelStyle->Directive[,FontSize->32]}},{4}->{{Labeled,label,Above,LabelStyle->Directive[,FontSize->32]}},{5}->{{Labeled,label,Above,LabelStyle->Directive[,FontSize->32]}},{6}->{{Labeled,label,Above,LabelStyle->Directive[,FontSize->32]}},{7}->{{Labeled,label,Above,LabelStyle->Directive[,FontSize->32]}},{8}->{{Labeled,label,Above,LabelStyle->Directive[,FontSize->32]}}}
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

Wrappers defined in `` Charting`ParserDump`$ApplicationWrapperFunctions `` which include `Labeled` appear to be handled generically.

`` Charting`ChartParser `` is used to process the chart data.  It calls 
`` Charting`ParserDump`processWrappers `` which contains the definition:

```
(* contexts stripped for brevity *)

processWrappers[obj_, d : h_[x_, y___], pos_, wrappers_List] /; 
  MemberQ[wrappers, h] :=
 Module[{data},
  appendProperty[obj, 
   "WrapperFunctions", {pos -> 
     Which[MemberQ[$SystemWrapperFunctions, h], data = x; {h, h[#1, y] &}, 
      MemberQ[$ApplicationWrapperFunctions, h], data = x; {h, y}, 
      MemberQ[$MetaWrapperFunctions, h], data = x; {h, y}, 
      MemberQ[$ModelWrapperFunctions, h], data = d["InputData"]; {h, d}, True, 
      dbPrint["processWrappers: ", h, " is not in any of the wrapper lists. "]]}]; 
   processWrappers[obj, data, pos, wrappers]
 ]
```

Note that for every Application Wrapper Function the same transformation is applied, i.e. `wrapper[foo, bar, baz]` -> `{wrapper, bar, baz}`.

I get lost in the definitions here but I cannot find anything that would handle `LableStyle` specifically.

Comment: I didn;t know about ``Charting`dbPrint = Print``. It is too time consuming to run a `Trace` on this sort of thing due to the volume of output. Given that `LabelStyle` is a documented option (note that same thing happens for `BaseStyle`) it appears to be a bug. How do you feel about adding "bugs" for this post?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Well it *looks* buggy but since I didn't finish walking through the code before I got tired I cannot really say.  Arguably it falls into the category of omission, which I suppose are bugs to some people and not to others.

Comment: I think if a documented option does not work then it is a bug -- just MHO

Comment: @Mike What about the `Labeled` options that make no sense within `BarChart`?

Comment: Thats pedantic! :) I am referring to options that clearly should work. I'd expect options that make no sense to be filtered out.

Comment: @Mike I genuinely wasn't trying to be a pest, I just wanted to understand your perspective.

Comment: no worries. I didn't interpret your comment as you being a pest!

Comment: I would suggest that the logical place for `LabelStyle` to be handled would be in ``Charting`resolveLabeledStatic`` (which is called from ``System`BarChartDump`renderLabels`` to generate graphics expressions for the labels). It is inside resolveLabeledStatic that the specific style for the label is combined with the global `LabelStyle` directives, but currently it is set up to expect label data like `{text, position, style}` rather than `{text, position, LabelStyle -> style}`.