# Is this a bug in TimelinePlot?

Tags: plotting

The function TimelinePlot has the option for "Alignment":

```
    Alignment /. Options[Labeled]
```

Results in:

```
    {Center, Baseline}
```

But if one tries to plug the options into a simple plot:

```
    TimelinePlot[
     {Labeled[Interval[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2018, 1, 1}}]
       , "Test"
       , Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}
    ]}]
```

I get the error:

[image: Error message from Mathematica]

Thank you for any suggestions!

Sincerely,

Mark

(Windows 7 and Mathematica 11.1.1.0)

Comment: I have tried different permutations of the parameters provided in the help page for alignment and can't find a format that is accepted. I expected that the default values (provided in the Options) would work.

Comment: It appears that, as a "wrapper," `TimelinePlot` treats `Labeled` in a special way (see also `BarChart`).  All of the examples in the documentation for `TimelinePlot` are not valid uses of `Labeled`. In particular, it uses the position keywords, `Above`, `Below`, `Before`, `After`, and `Automatic` that are not valid in a standalone `Labeled`.  Given those differences, it is not clear that `Labeled` inside `TimelinePlot` has the same `Labeled` options.

Comment: Related: [Screwy use of Labeled in BarChart — possible bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/screwy-use-of-labeled-in-barchart-possible-bug)

Comment: Thank you for the observation and related @Michael E2 !